# How to periodically change root password

Tags: password

I have 60 systems with different root passwords.

Every 3 months I have to change their passwords.

Currently I have to manually log into 60 systems and come up with 60 different passwords.

Is there a smart way to do this? Can I use Ansible for this kind of job?

Comment: Yes, you can use ansible. You probably can use a simple shell script too (especially if you have sudo + public key deployed on your server).

Comment: Whoever forces you to change the passwords, could have a reason for it and therefor have guidelines that must be followed. If the idea is to improve security, some scripting solutions could rather lower security instead of improving it.

Comment: If you have 60 systems, I would seriously consider setting up a central authentication server such as kerberos or 389ds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this is to:

1. Create a text file(*) containing the hostnames and the plaintext root passwords. Use whatever field separator you like - tabs are good.

   Ideally, you'd use a program like `makepasswd` or `pwgen` to generate passwords of sufficient length and complexity.   IMO, 16 characters are the absolute minimum to consider using these days, and the longer the better.

   e.g. if you have a list of the hostnames (one per line) in `hosts.txt`, using something like the following:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash

    rm -f passwords.txt
    while read -r host ; do
      printf "%s\t%s\n" "$host" "$(pwgen -r \''`$' -y -c -n 32 1)" >> passwords.txt
    done < hosts.txt
   ```

   (this uses `-r` to prevent single-quotes, backticks, and $ from being used in the password, because dealing with them in the single-quoted-string-inside-double-quotes `ssh` command shown below would be a PITA).

   Example run:

   ```
    $ ./generate-passwords.sh
    $ cat passwords.txt
    host1   >?Mg^un=-Ipd8ZkY^TUC,_Gf/PAs%=9t
    host2   XS4?oZ@[+U\,(XeYOBcp{E^Q;!]2]ex<
    host3   SfupD}=a\J;}TJqqX.r}Kj;ab>Z|\=S2
   ```

   You're going to need this list because otherwise you'll have no way of what the passwords are on the remote machines.
2. `ssh` into each host and use `chpasswd` to set the password.   To avoid having the password appear in plain text in the remote machine's process list, pre-encrypt the passwords on your local machine with `openssl passwd` and use `chpasswd`'s `-e` option (this is only "safe" if you're the only user of your machine....and for quite limited definitions of the word "safe").  In this example, I'm using the `-6` option for `SHA-512` hashing.

   ```
    #!/bin/bash

    while IFS=$'\t' read -r host pass; do
      enc=$(printf "%s" "$pass" | openssl passwd -6 stdin)
      ssh "$host" "echo 'root:$enc' | chpasswd -e"
    done < passwords.txt
   ```

This is really simple and primitive.  There's no error checking. Or logging.   But it does show the basic idea of how to use existing tools like `pwgen`, `openssl`, and `chpasswd` to automate password changes.

I used to use scripts similar to these every semester at a university where I worked to generate passwords for new students in particular courses where shell access to specific machines (which were isolated from the main network) was required.  The list was printed and cut into strips, and each user was given their password on showing their ID....this was far from perfect, but much better than having a default "password" that everyone knew.

Obviously, most of the time you'll be logging in to the remote machines with an authorised ssh key and not using a password at all...but root passwords are still useful for logins at the console (or with a BMC or other remote-management facilities) in case of emergencies.

---

(*) Because this `passwords.txt` file is plain text, you need to be very careful about permissions and who has access to it, but that's mostly outside of the scope of this Q&A.

I suggest `chmod 600` and encrypting the file with [gpg](https://www.gnupg.org/) - only decrypt it when you need to use it.    I'd also suggest keeping the encrypted version in `git` or some other revision control system so that you don't lose your history of old passwords to try if the password update failed on some particular hosts for some reason (e.g. it was offline at the time)

Or use [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) to combine both `gpg` and `git`.

Comment: I would suggest if the local system allows it, to replace `openssl passwd` with `mkpasswd`. That way new hash algorithm might get supported earlier (eg: of use: `mkpasswd -m YESCRYPT test` or `echo test | mkpasswd -s -m YESCRYPT` . Example chosen specifically about newer YESCRYPT not yet supported in openssl)

Comment: AFAICT, `mkpasswd` is in the `whois` package (at least on debian), which is far less likely to be installed than `openssl`.   I have no idea why a general purpose tool like `mkpasswd `is in `whois`.

Comment: doh. I didn't check this and assumed it was coming along other *passwd tools. You're right